# TextView doesn't print a string on the main screen

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

In my XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"


    android:textColor="@color/black"
    />
```

And in my Java File:

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1); myTextView.setText("Local Time:" + localTime);
```

But still it's not printing anything on my screen. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What color is you text? Try setting it to another color.

Comment: Set it to black, but it didn't work

Comment: I don't generally use this line: android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

Comment: Removed it and it still doesn't work

Comment: could you please share your full xml

Comment: add this in RelativeLayout android:background="#FFFFFF"

Comment: Nothing still came up

Answer (score 1):

In my XML file

```
<Text View
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding Bottom="2dip"
    android:padding Top="6dip"
    android:text Color="#9EEBF5"
    android:text Size="16sp"
    android:text Style="bold" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your text to another color.  In your xml.

```
android:textColor="yourcolor"
```

and in a resource xml

```
<color name="yourcolor">#F5DC49</color>
```

I think  you might need

```
@`android:style/TextAppearance.Large`
```

I think that ?android is a typo in your stuff

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="Try"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

mainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView t1;
    String localTime = "10A.m";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        t1.setText("Local Time: " + localTime);
    }

}
```

Comment: It printed "Local Time 10A.m", but not the local time.